# Does Vladimir's ultimate increase Ignite's damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm wondering if the activation of [Vladimir's](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/champions/8/vladimir_the_crimson_reaper) ult increases the true damage from Ignite. Using his ult before Ignite could mean all the difference when bursting down an enemy champion upon reaching level six. Any answers that shed light on this would be helpful!

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, Hemoplague will amplify the damage from Ignite.

---

According to [Hemoplague's ability details](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vladimir_the_Crimson_Reaper/Ability_Details#Hemoplague),

> Hemoplague amplifies any kind of damage, including [true damage](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/True_damage).

Also, according to the notes on [Ignite](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ignite),

> This spell's damage **can be increased** through spells that increase damage from all sources such as  **Hemoplague**,  Diplomatic Immunity,  Torment, and  Cutthroat.

Answer (score 1):

actually such things do increase ignite true dmg

another example is shacos passive (he deals additional dmg when attacking from behind) when he uses smite while standing in the back of a minion/dragon etc, he deal extra dmg

Comment: Any chance you have pics or vids of this? That's crazy, and I'd love to see it!

Comment: Same with Poppy's ult and Swain's Torment. Running ignite and DFG on both of these champions is pretty scary!

Answer (score 1):

True Damage only ignores armor, magic resistance and damage reduction effects.
All effects that increase damage taken by the target still apply for it.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/True_Damage

```
* True damage is unaffected by damage reductions such as  Exhaust.  
* True damage is not amplified by the masteries  Havoc or  Executioner  
* True damage can be amplified by abilities such as  Poppy's  
  Diplomatic Immunity,  Swain's  Torment and  Talon's  Cutthroat.
```

Answer (score 0):

It increases the damage of Ignite, and it increases Death Fire Grasp's damage as well!

Answer (score 0):

[Vladimir's](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/champions/8/vladimir_the_crimson_reaper) ult, Hemoplague, increases damage taken by enemies hit by 12% for 5 seconds. [Ignite](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ignite) deals 170 damage at level 6, so casting Hemoplague before Ignite will boost the damage up to 190. 20 extra damage might not seem like much, but I've gotten away from fights with health in the single-digits...every little bit counts.